# Remove invalid JSON characters from an object's string property - ex: myObj.stringProp

Tags: c#, json, wcf, parsing, invalid-characters

I've got a WCF service returning a serialized object which I parse client side using `$.parseJSON()`

Works great 99% of the time. Unfortunately, it occasionally serializes invalid characters (ex: "â€¨â€¨") and causes the parser to crash.

So far those characters are pretty much the only ones I've come across that give me problems, and I did find a way to encode that string to remove that.. but it seems sloppy:

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(myString);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
var sResult = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

One method that was working prior to these characters showing up (I had some issues with other invalid chars before this) was to `$.stringify()` the result first and then parse it. But it seems that it doesn't handle this case.

Without having to change the way every object is serialized application wide, is there a better way to do this on just one property?